Is there a way to set the global casting rule in numpy?
I'm trying to make a simple 3D editor/renderer in python, so I'm using numpy. I'm adding one thing to another, and I know I can do this: A = numpy.multiply(A, B, casting='safe') where A is a float64 and B is a int64. That will work fine, but if I try A *= B it spews out this error:
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

I want a way to set a global casting of 'safe' and not 'same_type,' is there any way to do that?

Note that Numpy cannot do any operation like that on different types. As a result, Numpy casts one of the array before the actual operation (i.e. it creates a new possibly-big array). Thus, for A *= B, you can use A *= B.astype(A.dtype) which should be computationally equivalent / equally fast. It is not very convenient though. I do not think it is possible to change the behavior globally since Numpy uses the casting='same_kind' in the definition of the function (unless some global variable can override this which would be very unsafe since it will certainly break codes).

Are you sure A is float? A *= B raises this error if A is int and B is float.  Basically the dtype of A cannot be changed.  So only results that can be 'same kind' cast to int work.  A variant A[:]=A*B works, with possible truncation on casting to int.

@hpaulj Your right, A is an int and B is a float.

I found a simple fix. Before the main game loop I added this: A = A.astype(np.float64)
This makes A a float, (which casting from an int is a safe casting) and fixes the problem. It's not what I was looking for but it works.
